# Using Moq with overloaded method

Tags: c#, moq

Why doesn't my Moq Test resolve to the appropriate Method.

Calling the Service in my Test:

```
var service = new EmployeeService(mockScoreRep);
```

Uses the following Method

```
public EmployeeService(ICMS_Repository cmsrepository)
{
    _cmsRepository = cmsrepository;            
}       

public EmployeeService(IRepository<Score> scoreRep)
{
    _scoreRepository = scoreRep;
}
```

I get the following Error:

```
Cannot convert from 'Moq.Mock<IRepository<Score>>' to 'ICMS_Repository'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you want the mock *object*, not the wrapper:

```
var service = new EmployeeService(mockScoreRep.Object);
```

In other words, you want to pass an `IRepository<Score>` - not a `Moq.Mock<IRepository<Score>>`.